# What kind of image processing can i apply to these captchas to make them readable for tesseract?

Tags: tesseract, captcha

I'm learning how to use tesseract in python to bypass different captchas so as i know before giving captcha's image to tesseract you have to do some image processing first. Here is the problem: What kind of image processing can i apply to these captchas to make them readable for tesseract (https://i.stack.imgur.com/n91Sk.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/F26n4.jpg)

Comment: duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410530/python-tesseract-recognize-this-captcha/68428708#68428708

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Tesseract - Recognize this captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410530/python-tesseract-recognize-this-captcha)